# I want to add a pop up contact form

Tags: html, css, forms, validation, layout

I want to add a modal pop up on [Feel Tourism](https://www.feeltourism.com/). My site is designed in HTML code. I want to add this pop up to homepage of my HTML site. This Pop up should appear only once to a user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',
function() {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = 'flex';

});
document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click',
function() {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = 'none';
});
```